# How to sum tuples? Because original sum concatenates them

Tags: python, api, dictionary, for-loop, key

I have a large dictionary in which I am scanning an API and adding values to based on if the shots taken in a hockey game are goals or not. Here is my code right now...

```
for key in contents['liveData']['plays']['allPlays']:
        # for plays in key['result']['event']:
            # print(key)
        if (key['result']['event'] == "Shot"):
            #print(key['result']['event'])
            scoordinates = (key['coordinates']['x'], key['coordinates']['y'])
            if scoordinates not in shots:
                shots[scoordinates] = (1, 0)
            else:
                shots[scoordinates] += (1, 0)
        if (key['result']['event'] == "Goal"):
            #print(key['result']['event'])
            gcoordinates = (key['coordinates']['x'], key['coordinates']['y'])
            if gcoordinates not in shots:
                shots[gcoordinates] = (1, 1)
            else:
                shots[gcoordinates] += (1, 1)
```

I was trying to add two values to the dict by using parentheses, but this doesn't work because whenever there is a duplicate coordinate shot the table will add the value like this (1,0, 1, 1) instead of doing (2,1). Is this possible? I was thinking there might be a simple formatting fix here, but I am not totally sure.

Comment: So what you're really asking about is element-wise addition of tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sum instead of +=:

```
a = tuple(map(sum, zip(a, b)))
```

So for this situation use:

```
shots[gcoordinates] = tuple(map(sum, zip((1, 1), shots[gcoordinates])))
```

Comment: Would there be any way to make another column that is equal to the shots (first number) divided by the goals (second number)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function to sum tuples:

```
import operator
def sum_tuples(tuple_1, tuple_2):
    return tuple(map(operator.add, tuple_1, tuple_2))
```